# Create python property function dynamically

Tags: python, python-2.7, properties

I want to create property method dynamically.

It means, for example, i want first class A to be equivalent with second one.

Is there any way?

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self._a = 10
    self.createPropertyMethod(a, self._a, getFunc, setFunc, delFunc)

  def createPropertyMethod(self, name, value, getFunc, setFunc, delFunc)
     #TODO
```

.

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self._a = 10

  @property
  def a(self):
    return getFunc(self._a)
  @a.setter
  def a(self, value):
    setFunc(self._a, value)
  @a.deleter
  def a(self):
    delFunc(self._a)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't, not on *instances*. The `property` object needs to be part of the class for the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) on which it relies to work.

You can use the [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__), [`__setattr__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__) and [`__delattr__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__delattr__) hooks instead to proxy attribute access dynamically.

Comment: Does creating a decorator on class would work what @asleea wants to achieve ? Well i am not very much comfortable in the new style classes thing.

Comment: @kingsdeb: a class decorator would alter the class, not the instance. So, yes, you can create `property` objects in the decorator, add those to the class and have them work.

Comment: @Martin Pieters -Would you show me such a code with little more explanation please?

Comment: @kingsdeb: no, because that's outside scope of this question.